# Java code to create an image containing three code128 barcodes

Tags: java, image, barcode, multiline

I would like to write a Java code to generate barcode in three line. The code below is creating a barcode in one line. It will be really helpful if you have any solution for this.

```
Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(codeValue);
barcode.setDrawingText(false);
barcode.setBarHeight(200);
barcode.setBarWidth(5);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(500, 500, 
BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
barcode.draw(g, 6, 30);
```

after this im creating an image for the barcode.

```
File f = new File("Path\\Bar_Img.jpeg");
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
     // Let the barcode image handler do the hard work
     BarcodeImageHandler.writeJPEG(barcode, fileOutputStream);
```

so this will create a single line barcode. but i want to create a single image with three line barcode

[image]

Comment: Three codeValues would be needed, printing thee barcodes.

Answer (score 0):

Im aint sure what is the type of codeValue, but maybe try to put there an array which contains different values, and put this into for loop like below.

```
String codeValue[] = new String[3];

codeValue[0] = "Some text";
codeValue[1] = "Some text";
codeValue[2] = "Some text";

for (i = 0; i < codeValue.length; i++) {
Barcode barcode = BarcodeFactory.createCode128(codeValue[i]);
 barcode.setDrawingText(false);
 barcode.setBarHeight(200);
 barcode.setBarWidth(5);

BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(500, 500, 
 BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);

 Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
 barcode.draw(g, 6, 30);

}
System.out.println("Loop over");
```

Comment: Yeah but i want to print the three barcode into single image.    File f = new File("H:\\My Documents\\Tes_Bar\\Bar_Img.jpeg");
     FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(f);
         BarcodeImageHandler.writeJPEG(barcode, fileOutputStream);

Comment: Hmm.. maybe try to combine those images into bigger one?